# Create KMZ file from KML file Programatically in C#

Tags: c#, kml, google-earth, kmz

I have a number of kml file I am generating in a directory.

I am wondering if there is a way to group them all into a kmz file programmatically in C#. With a name and description displayed in google earth.

Thanks and best regards,

```
private static void combineAllKMLFilesULHR(String dirPath)
{
    string kmzPath = "outputULHR.kmz";

    string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    string rootKml = appPath + @"\" + dirPath + @"\doc.kml";
    Console.WriteLine(appPath + @"\"+ dirPath);
    String[] filepaths = Directory.GetFiles(appPath + @"\" + dirPath);

    using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(kmzPath, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
    {
        archive.CreateEntryFromFile( rootKml, "doc.kml");
        foreach (String file in filepaths)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file);
            if(!file.Equals(rootKml))
                archive.CreateEntryFromFile( file, Path.GetFileName(file) );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being a KMZ file a zip archive, you can use the [ZipArchive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive(v=vs.110).aspx) class to generate it.

```
string kmzPath = "output.kmz";
string rootKml = "doc.kml";
string referencedKml = "someother.kml";

using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(kmzPath, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
{
    archive.CreateEntryFromFile(rootKml, "doc.kml");
    archive.CreateEntryFromFile(referencedKml, "someother.kml");
}
```

just remember to name the default kml as *doc.kml*, from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives?csw=1):

> Put the default KML file (doc.kml, or whatever name you want to give
>   it) at the top level within this folder. Include only one .kml file.
>   (When Google Earth opens a KMZ file, it scans the file, looking for
>   the first .kml file in this list. It ignores all subsequent .kml
>   files, if any, in the archive. If the archive contains multiple .kml
>   files, you cannot be sure which one will be found first, so you need
>   to include only one.)

Comment: Thanks alberto. While the kmz file is being created, it is only displaying the contents of the doc.kml file. Also does this work when I have many kml files that I want to archive. I have updated the original post with the method I am using.